# GitHub Actions: How to run test inside container

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-actions-services

I wanted to run django test cases inside container.
I am able to pull private image from docker hub. but when I ran command to test, It is failed to run.

Anyone tried running test cases inside the container.

```
jobs:
test:
container:
  image: abcd
  credentials:
    username: "<username>"
    password: "<password>"

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Display Python version
    run: |
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install -r requirements/dev.txt
  - name: run test
    run: |
      python3 manage.py test
```

Comment: Show your (minimal) action YAML. Running tests in docker is simply a matter of `docker run your/image your-test-command` (or even better, with docker-compose).

Comment: @DannyB I updated the YAML. I am fetching image from dockerhub directly under container command.

Comment: And what is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In my experience, I found out that using GitHub's `container` instruction causes more confusion than simply running whatever you want on the runner itself, as if you are running it on your own machine.

A big majority of the tests I am running on GitHub actions are running in containers, and some require private DockerHub images.

I always do this:

1. Create a `docker-compose.yml` for development use, so I can test things locally.
2. Usually in CI, you might want slightly different things in your `docker-compose` (for example, no volume mappings) - if this is the case, I am creating another `docker-compose.yml` in a `.ci` subfolder.
3. My `docker-compose.yml` contains a `test` service, that runs whatever test (or test suite) I want.

Here is a sample GitHub actions file I am using:

```
name: Test
on:
  pull_request:
  push: { branches: master }

jobs:
  test:
    name: Run test suite
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      COMPOSE_FILE: .ci/docker-compose.yml
      DOCKER_USER: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
      DOCKER_PASS: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }}

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Login to DockerHub
      run: docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS

    - name: Build docker images
      run: docker-compose build

    - name: Run tests
      run: docker-compose run test
```

Of course, this entails setting up the two mentioned secrets, but other than that, I found this method to be:

- Reliable
- Portable (I switched from Travis CI with the same approach easily)
- Compatible with dev environment
- Easy to understand and reproduce both locally and in CI

Comment: I agree, the container instruction is really difficult to use. Better use your approach or just docker run containerimage cmd

Comment: So how does github know that the tests have failed or passed (as they are run inside a Docker container)?

Comment: Running a command that executes tests from the host, using docker or docker-compose will also exit with non zero code if the command fails in the container.

Comment: @DannyB do you have a sample codebase with this workflow?

Comment: @dondrzzy - I am using this workflow mainly for private complex apps, but I have a similar one in at least two public repos: [here](https://github.com/DannyBen/alf/blob/master/.github/workflows/test.yml) and [here](https://github.com/DannyBen/rush-cli/blob/master/.github/workflows/test.yml).

Comment: @DannyB do you have a repo on GitHub that uses this approach?

Comment: Yes, one comment above :)