# Unable to access secrets from Dockerfile in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am using the following project as a [baseline](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action) to create a Docker container action.

The problem that I have is that I need to be able to access my secrets inside my Dockerfile. I tried almost all the tricks that I knew.

Retrieve the secret

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=API_ENDPOINT \
   export API_ENDPOINT=$(cat /run/secrets/API_ENDPOINT)
```

Docker build is not happy because the `--mount option requires BuildKit`. I tried to set `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`, but I had zero success.

How can I pass the secrets? I created an env var at the top of my action (global), and all the steps have complete visibility of that secret.

```
env:
  API_ENDPOINT: ${{secrets.API_ENDPOINT}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to create an action inside a container, rather than run arbitrary container commands? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364989/github-actions-how-to-run-test-inside-container/64373702#64373702

Comment: Please show what you tried and what errors you got. We don't know what "almost all the tricks I knew" means :)